# regex to match and retrieve some tokens

Tags: java, regex

The strings I am interested in look like something like the followings
`a1.foo`, `a2.bar`, `a3.whatever`

Now I need to retrieve the number.
So I wrote this piece of code (in Java), thinking it would work, but it does not.
Could anyone please let me know what is wrong with my pattern?

```
final String testInput = "a2.foo";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a(\\d*)\\.([^\\w])");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(testInput);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println("n = " + matcher.group(1));
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("NOT MATCHED");
}
```

This prints `NOT MATCHED`, while I expected it to print `2`

Comment: `\\.([^\\w])` matches a `.` followed by a single non-word character. All your examples have a word character following the `.` http://regexpal.com/ is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong as `([^\\w])` will match only one non-word character. You probably wanted more than 1 word character hence `(\\w+)`

However you can use this lookahead:

```
Pattern.compile("a(\\d*)(?=\\.)");
```

Comment: But I also want to make sure if a string like `a2` (not followed by a dot) will not get matched.

Comment: `a2 (not followed by a dot)` won't be matched by lookahead.

Comment: @aliteralmind To be honest, I have no idea what you are talking about. What conflicts with what?

Comment: @aliteralmind I believed you misread. I said I also wanted stuff WITHOUT the dot would NOT get matched.